# Trying to increase the performance of my GAE app

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, appstats

I am trying to use memcache to improve the performance.
Here is my model:

```
class ABC(db.Model):
   some_property = db.StringProperty()
# more properties

class XYZ(db.Model):
   another_property = db.StringProperty()
   abc = db.ReferenceProperty(ABC,collection_name="xyzs")
# more properties
```

I have only two entities of ABC and 800 entities of XYZ
So, one of the feature of the app is to provide the excel sheet for all XYZ. The excel sheet has two columns.
First column is "another_property" and the second column is "some_property"(from ABC reference).

```
xyzs = XYZ.all()
for xyz in xyzs:
   logging.info(xyz.another_property)
   logging.info(xyz.abc.some_property)
```

With this approach,`xyz.abc.some_property` was making a datastore call every-time
[image: Reference property making datstore query]

[image: RPC call]

Seeing this i decided to use memcache to store the abc reference in memory.
With memcache in use, i didn't see any major change in response time.

```
abcId = XYZ.abc.get_value_for_datastore(xyz).id()
#Get ABC reference from memcache if present else bring it from datastore and add it to memcahce.
```

[image: Memcache]

[image: Memcache RPC]

Can please someone why i am not seeing any performance gain?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do a get memcache for each XYZ entity.
I solved it by doing a bulk get memcache https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_get_multi

The pseudo code :

```
abcIds = [str(XYZ.abc.get_value_for_datastore(xyz).id() for xyz in xyzs]
abcs = memcache.get_multi(abcIds) #This gives me a dictionary of id as key and ABC reference property as value
```

Here is the snapshot of improved version of my app.[image: Improved Memcahce]

Posting it as it might help others.
PS: I have a feeling this can also be improved.Help me in improving the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably will note, if you are starting out consider using ndb.

Now to my answer, you should use a prefetch reference property approach which is a lot more efficient see write up by nick johnson http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine

Which basically collects all the keys in the reference property, then does a single get of all the entities.  You may find it performs as well as memcache, plus if entities are evicted from memcache (which will happen) you get all of your data.

Comment: Moved my app from db to ndb but the performance deteriorated.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998450/can-someone-explain-the-difference-between-this-two-ahstats-generated-timeline